# why exim4-daemon-heavy is removed when i remove mysql 8.0 / mysql 5.7

Tags: apt, dpkg, mysql, exim

When I remove mysql 8.0/mysql 5.7 using this command:

```
apt-get --purge -y remove mysql*
```

it also removes `exim4-daemon-heavy` package. As far as I know exim is not dependent on mysql. So why does it removes exim?

I get the following log on mysql removal:-

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
exim4-daemon-heavy* libmysqlclient18* mysql-common* mysql-community-client-core* mysql-community-server-core*
```

I don't want `exim4-daemon-heavy` to be removed. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Investigate with `apt depends` and `apt rdepends`. Read `man apt`.

Answer (score 2):

```
apt-get --purge -y remove mysql*
```

means "Remove any package whose name contains `mysq` (`mysq` followed by zero or more `l`). This includes the MySQL *client* libs that are needed by exim4-daemon-heavy.

Use

```
apt-get --purge -y remove 'mysql.*server'
```

to only remove the MySQL *server* packages.

Comment: Thank you Florian Diesch and waltinator. Your answers really helped me in solving my issue.